# How to use jquery animation in background?

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

Please check https://searchmgseo.com.au/smg/ I want to use the nav upon the jquery animated background.

Comment: use animation on body. and place nav or anything on it

Comment: Can you make that work for me? I am not able to implement the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the css position property of `.pg-canvas` to `absolute` either in your custom css style sheet:

```
.pg-canvas{
   position:absolute; 
}
```

**or** by adding the following code to one of your custom JS scripts:

```
$(".pg-canvas").css({"position":"absolute"});
```

You can run the above JS code in your console directly to see the change.

Comment: Thanks buddy.. you saved me day.